# Jquery.mousewheel:delta not change

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I try to use jquery.mousewheel plugn to develop a simple demo. However, the delta was never change.
    My code below:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#myImage").mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
                var a = $("#txtResult").val()=="NaN"?0:parseInt($("#txtResult").val());
                var b = delta;

                $("#txtResult").val(a+b);
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <img id="myImage" src="QQ截图20130119105432.png" style="width: 200px;height: 200px" />
        <input id="txtResult" type="text" value="0"/>
    </body>
```

When I operate my mouse wheel after move the mouse to the image, `$("#txtResult").val()` has never changed.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code is wrong. It should be like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#myImage").mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
        var a = parseInt($("#txtResult").val());
        var b = delta;

        $("#txtResult").val(a + b);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

`parseInt` will parse `null` to `0` so additional check is unneccessary.
Also, in this case, `event.stopPropagation();` is useless.

Comment: Hi, i test the application again and found that the reason for the bug was that the version of jquery.js did not support jquery.mousewheel.js. After I replace jquery.js with a low version, the code works well. However, I need to use the latest version. Any idea?

Comment: I solved it by myself. It is because the version of mousewheel.js can not match jquery.js